# Want to filter result by using two filters "event start day" and "event start time" in one view for showing upcomming events?

Tags: views

I want to show a view of upcoming events. I have added *event start day* filter to my view, it's showing today's events as well as upcoming events.

This functionality is working fine but problem is that  it's showing all  events of today not on the basis of time but it's showing morning's event whose time is passed away. It must only filter the values on the basis of *current time and coming time*(current day and upcoming days).

I want to add one more filter *event start time* filter. How to add two filters(event start date and event start time) in one view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [Views between dates filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter) module. Or you can create filter by selecting event date and time from the content.

**Views Between Dates Filter:**

> This Views filter provides the between date functionality you've been looking for by answering the question: "What events are on this date?" It displays all content (comparing start and end dates) occurring on a specified date.
>
> Creating this functionality with standard Date filters requires two filters: start date less than or equal (<=) to the supplied date and end date greater than or equal (>=) to the supplied date. The problem is two filters means users must enter a date range, when technically selecting "September" is a range: September 1st to the 30th.
>
> It compares two date fields with one supplied date. Effectively it is the opposite of the standard Date Views "between" operator, which compares one date field with two supplied dates.

Comment: !!! ok i will try then let you know its working or not

Comment: "event start day" filter already working fine i dont require any more module for this ..i just want to add "event start time" filter so that only those events will show which belongs to current time and about to come time and same functionality for days also